# Cauchy's integral formula with special contour 4

Tags: integration, cauchy-integral-formula

suppose $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ is a path of integration with $ \gamma(a)=0, \gamma(b)=1 \ and \ \pm i \notin\gamma([a,b]) $
Show that,
$$    \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{\pi}{4} + k \pi $$

I would try to apply Cauchy's integral formula. Therefore i can split the integrand in partial fractions with singularities at $ \pm i$
How do i have to choose my contour such that it fullfilles the conditions at the beginning.

Comment: Maybe i have to  construct  a closed path of integration. out of $ \gamma(a)=0, \gamma(b)=1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Gamma$ be another path: a straight line connecting from $1$ to $0$.

By residue theorem (let $n$ and $m$ be the winding numbers around $z=+i$ and $z=-i$ respectively),

$$
\begin{align}
\oint_{\gamma+\Gamma}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}
&=2\pi i \left(n\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}\frac1{1+z^2}+ m\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}\frac1{1+z^2}\right) \\
&=\pi(-n+m) \\
&=\pi(m-n)
\end{align}
$$

Since
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\int^0_1\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\operatorname{arctan}t\bigg\vert^{t=0}_{t=1}=-\frac{\pi}4$$

Thus,
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\frac{\pi}4+(m-n)\pi$$

---

Doing without residue theorem:

Firstly, recognize that
$$\int\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\frac1{2i}\int\left(\frac1{z+i}-\frac1{z-i}\right)dz=\frac{\ln(z+i)-\ln(z-i)}{2i}$$

Thus,
$$\int\frac{dz}{1+z^2}= \frac{\ln(z+i)-\ln(z-i)}{2i} \bigg\vert^{z=1}_{z=0}$$

Considering the multi-value-ness of $\ln$ you would obtain the desired result.

In essence,
$$\begin{align}
 \frac{\ln(z+i)-\ln(z-i)}{2i}\bigg\vert^{z=1}_{z=0}
&=\frac{\ln(1+i)-\ln(1-i)+\ln(i)-\ln(-i)}{2i}\\
&=\frac{\ln(\sqrt2e^{i(\pi/4+2m\pi)})-\ln(\sqrt2e^{i(-\pi/4+2n\pi)})}{2i}\\
&~~~~+\frac{\ln(e^{i(\pi/2+2p\pi)})-\ln(e^{i(-\pi/2+2q\pi)})}{2i}\\
&=i\frac{\pi/4+\pi/4+\pi/2+\pi/2+2N\pi}{2i}\\
&=\frac{\pi}4+N’\pi\\
\end{align}
$$
where $N’$ is an arbitrary integer.

Comment: I am  not allowed to uses  the residue theorem.  Therefore i wanted to split the integrand into partial fractions. How do u choose $ \gamma_1,  \gamma_2 $?

Comment: Dont i have to enclose my singularities with $ \Gamma$

Comment: @Steven33 Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you:) Do i have to  parameterize the straight line connecting from 0 to 1 and put that into my definition of the  contour integral, meaning: z=t $ \forall t \in [0,1]$. Ok i see that makes not such a big difference.:)

Comment: Thank you very much:) You made my day. Thank you:) I made a horrible mistake.

Comment: @Steven33 Please see my edited answer too.

Comment: I saw that. Now its clear, that i musnt only add $ 2 k i \pi $, when i want to evaluate ln(..). I have to add the argument of my complex point, too. Thank you very much:)